# How to get value from json object if key is stored in variable?

Tags: php, json

I have a json object something like

```
$json = '
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "toppings": [
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}';
```

from which I can get value like this

```
$yummy = json_decode($json, true);

echo $yummy['toppings'][2]['type']; //Maple
```

If key is stored in variable

```
$key= '["toppings"][2]["type"]';
```

how to get value from json object $yummy.

I have tried

```
$d= $yummy.$key;
```

I am provided keys in a variable so I don't know count of keys and key names. Json objects and keys are dynamically created.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"JSON object"* or *"JSON array"*. [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (an object or an array). In order to use it, it needs to be decoded back into the data structure used to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use `eval`, but its use is discouraged, so I am obliged to copy the disclaimer in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) first:

> **Caution**
>
> The `eval()` language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

You should look at other ways to encode the key sequence. But just in case, here is how you would do it with `eval`:

```
echo eval("return \$yummy$key;");
```

#### Safe method

A way to do this without `eval` is to iterate over the keys within the `$key` string, and find the resulting value as you go:

```
function getByKey($obj, $key) {
    preg_match_all('~\[("(?:\\\\.|[^"])*"|\d+)\]~', $key, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $result = $obj;
    foreach ($matches as $k) $obj = $obj[json_decode($k[1])];
    return $obj;
}

echo getByKey($yummy, $key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have executed  json_decode  you have the content in an array so you can use the var as index of the array

but your string is not and index  of an array is only a string so you should use a set of var for get the set of index  (or you shold manage your string for build a set of var) eg:

```
$key1 = 'toppings';
$key2 = 2;
$key3 = 'type';

echo = $yummy[$ke1][$key2][$key3];
```

Comment: thank you @scaisEdge, Unfortunately I am provided keys in a variable so I don't know count of keys and key names. Json objects and keys are dynamically created.